# delay or setitimeout in ajax php codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have ajax call to calling a php function like this :

```
$('#btn-footer').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $("#id_user_edit").val();
            var id_perusahaan = $('#id_perusahaan').val();
            //console.log(id_perusahaan);
            var nama = $('#nama_edit').val();
            var username = $('#username_edit').val();
            var password = $('#password_edit').val();
            var departement = $('#kode_Departement_edit').val();
            var jabatan = $('#jabatan').val();
            var perusahaan = $('#kode_perusahaan_edit').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_member/update_user' ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id: id,
                    id_perusahaan: id_perusahaan,
                    nama: nama,
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    departement: departement,
                    jabatan: jabatan,
                    perusahaan : perusahaan
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(obj) {

                    alert('Update Success');
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
```

this is the html :

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="box-content">

                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">User's id : </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="id_user_edit" id="id_user_edit" autofocus>
                                <select id="id_perusahaan" name="kode_perusahaan">
                                    <option>PS</option>
                                    <option>JFS</option>
                                    <option>SLA</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Nama User : </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="nama" id="nama_edit">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Nama Login : </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="username" id="username_edit">                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Password : </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password_edit">                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Departement : </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select id="kode_Departement_edit" name="kode_Departement">
                                    <option>Accounting</option>
                                    <option>Armada</option>
                                    <option>Ekspor & Impor</option>
                                    <option>Finance</option>
                                    <option>HRD</option>
                                    <option>Inventory</option>
                                    <option>IT</option>
                                    <option>Legal & Claim</option>
                                    <option>Marketing</option>
                                    <option>Operational</option>
                                    <option>Purchasing</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Jabatan : </label>
                            <div class="controls">

                                <select id="jabatan" name="jabatan">
                                    <option>Administrator</option>
                                    <option>MD</option>
                                    <option>Manager</option>
                                    <option>Assisten Manager</option>
                                    <option>Kepala Bagian</option>
                                    <option>Staff</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Perusahaan : </label>
                            <div class="controls">

                                <select id="kode_perusahaan_edit" name="perusahaan">
                                    <option>Tresnamuda Sejati</option>
                                    <option>Jameson Freight Semesta</option>
                                    <option>Meridian Port</option>
                                    <option>Samudera Daka Lines</option>
                                    <option>SLA</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
            </div>                    
        </div>
```

I want to adding some delay or setTimeOut in ajax jquery. The html above (this is a modal bootstrap) is used to update some data in a row of a table. The problem is : when I updating all of the data, the data is not updating. I dont know how, because JSON that was created is true. I think, with setTImeout, updating will be success, How an I make it true ?

Comment: Do you get any errors from console?

Comment: Nothin, the problem is, when I just update one field, is success. But, when I update all, it is not working. Perhaps, with delay will be solved...'

Comment: There is no delaying process for this situation. The ajax request will returned success after all the operation done either one field or all field updating. Can post your php code for, wanna see the server side process that you made.